# Throttled 2-way server sync in Apollo Client 2.0

Tags: redux, graphql, apollo-client, data-synchronization

I have a ‘TODO list app’ that currently uses Apollo Client 1.0, Redux and Redux Saga. When I edit any item in my TODO list, it gets updated in various bits of UI immediately and is then synced with the sever after a couple of seconds. Throttling is necessary here because otherwise every single key press would cause a network request. When a todo is edited in another client and the new data arrives via a GraphQL subscription, a corresponding list item updates immediately unless it's being changed (an incoming edit is ignored in this case).

I'd like to replace Redux and Redux Saga with Apollo 2.0 as my current app code is pretty verbose and rather hard-to-debug. I'd like to simply use the Query/Mutation abstractions when dealing with my UI and just delegate throttling to some apollo-link.

What's the best way to do this? How do I achieve a throttled 2-way sync for my list of items while keeping local UI updates instant?

Interestingly, this is what Meteor can do out of box with its bespoke data sync protocol :–)